# Generic procedure in aws Redshift db

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I am trying to develop generic procedure in AWS Redshift DB which can accept table name, schema name as input parameters and while calling the procedure I am getting:

> SQL Error [500310] [42601]: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error

My procedure is:

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE purgingtbl(vschema IN  VARCHAR,
                                        vtable  IN VARCHAR,
                                        columnname IN VARCHAR)
AS $$
DECLARE
 Srcedate            VARCHAR(15);

BEGIN
    Raise info 'vschema = %, vtable = %,columnname = %', vschema,vtable,columnname;

select into Srcedate count(*) from 'vschema'.'vtable' where src_proc_dt < (Current_date - 90) and 'columnname' is NOT NULL;
     ---RAISE INFO 'Date in  Landingzone table greater than 90 days is = %', Srcedate;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call purgingtbl('schemaname', 'tablename');
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

This part looks a little strange:

```sql
select into Srcedate count(*) from 'vschema'.'vtable'
```

The syntax for `SELECT INTO` is:

```
SELECT
[ TOP number ] [ ALL | DISTINCT ]
* | expression [ AS output_name ] [, ...]
INTO [ TEMPORARY | TEMP ] [ TABLE ] new_table
[ FROM table_reference [, ...] ]
```

So, it should probably be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Srcedate FROM 'vschema'.'vtable' WHERE ...
```

You can test it by running it as a normal command, outside the stored procedure.